# Implementing contextual action bar disables row click highlighting

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, contextual-action-bar

I've implemented a single row contextual action bar following the [instructions from Google](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB).  The instructions say to add an `OnLongClickListener` to each view and since I'm using a `CustomAdapter`, I implemented it on each row using this code:

```
   @Override
   public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
       final ViewHolder holder;
       final View tempView = convertView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

                convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

                public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                    if (mActionMode != null) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    mActionMode = getSherlockActivity().startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
                    view.setSelected(true);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

However, using that code disables the normal click, so I added an `OnClickListener` to each view:

```
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

                tempView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));

                final Intent details = new Intent(this, Details.class);
                startActivity(details);
            }
    });
```

This more or less works, but seems hacky and the background color change isn't as "smooth" as the normal one.  I also have another `ListView` where I'm using a `MultiChoiceModeListener` and setting the `ChoiceMode` to `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL`, so users can select more than one row, and the normal row click works fine.

Comment: Why aren't you just using [`setOnItemLongClickListener()` on `ListView`](http://goo.gl/TxgRY)?

Comment: Didn't know I could.  I was just following Google's documentation.  I can try that though.

Comment: "Google's documentation" was a bit of sample code, nothing more.

Comment: @CommonsWare that worked much better.  Thanks for the heads up.